# Where can I find the pending amount from invoices in DynamicsAX Database?

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

This is what I already know, Tables for open invoices:

- "CustTransOpen"
- "CustInvoiceJour"
- "CustTrans"

I've been working on this for a while without a clue, there must be a way to get the pending amount or at least to know if these invoices have been paid.

I already looked on all the Microsoft documentation with no success, hope you can help me.

Comment: Well this seems pretty broad and in need of details perhaps?

Comment: Are you trying to figure this out from AX using `X++` or SQL?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss what kind of detail could help? here is the documentation for these tables 
[CustTrans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/custtrans.aspx) 
[CustTransOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/CustTransOpen.aspx)
[CustInvoiceJour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/CustInvoiceJour.aspx) 
I already check but it wasn't really helpfull.

Comment: @AlexKwitny I'm using SQL.

Comment: "I've been working on this for a while" > Please show what you have tried so far, this makes it easier to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the AX Query to get the open balance in MST for a customer.  To do it in SQL, you can rewrite it and/or at least use this to maybe get towards what you want.

This code originates from `\Data Dictionary\Tables\CustTable\Methods\openInvoiceBalanceMST` in AX.

`this` below refers to `CustTable`

```
while select sum(AmountMST) from custTransOpen
    where custTransOpen.AccountNum  == this.AccountNum
       && custTransOpen.TransDate   >= _fromDate
       && custTransOpen.TransDate   <= _toDate
    exists join custTrans
        where custTrans.RecId       == custTransOpen.RefRecId
           && (custTrans.Invoice    != ''
           || (custTrans.Invoice    == '' && custTrans.AmountMST   > 0))
{
    openBalanceMST += custTransOpen.AmountMST;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex!. This solution isn't SQL but a quick rewrite put me on the right direction. **CustTrans.AmountMST** is the column that I was looking for.

Comment: If you have access to develop in `AX` it's much easier to help you when you're trying to pull some data like that. It's just not a cut & dry SQL query in some cases because of the business logic associated with the data.